# Getting handle of control with minimum TabIndex

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to get a handle to whichever control has the minimum TabIndex.  I've tried using GetNextDlgTabItem() and passing a 0 pointer for the second argument, but the returned handle isn't always the first one in the screen's tab order.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up keeping track of which field got focus on load and then just setting focus back to that when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Dirty method: Try looping through your collection of controls and keep track of the one with the smallest tab index, when the loop is complete you should be able to return the index of the control in that collection with the smallest tabindex property.

Comment: Thank you :o) I was hoping for something a little cleaner... if I can't come up with anything that's probably what I'll end up having to do

Answer (score 0):

```
        public Control GetFirstTabindexControl(Control container)
        {
            Control res= container.GetNextControl(container, true);
            if (!res.CanSelect)
                res= GetFirstTabindexControl(res);
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.